# Vuex this.$store undefined in "mounted" life cycle hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, paypal, vuex

I am currently integrating the Paypal service to my Vue project. I've referred to the official document and copied the code  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#6-verify-the-transaction. I was able to render the Paypal button, complete the transaction and receive an orderID. However, I am unable to send the orderID to my server due to the following error: this.$store is undefined. **Do note that**, I was able to reference this.$store in my **other components**. Below is my following code:

**Update**: I tried to console.log(this) in the onApprove method and it returns undefined. Is that the problem?

**Update** I've converted the OnApprove method and capture() method to arrow function and received a different error message this.$store.dispatch(...).then(...).err is not a function

**Update** I managed to fix the above error by changing .err() to .catch().

**Update** I faced another problem, sometimes which I click on the Paypal button, the external Paypal window will immediately close by itself. I have to click on the button a few time, to prevent this strange behaviour. I went to the console log and found this message as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { PRODUCT_PAYPAL } from "@/store/actions/products";

export default {
  mounted() {
    paypal
      .Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
              {
                amount: {
                  value: "0.01"
                }
              }
            ]
          });
        },
         onApprove: (data, actions) => {
          return actions.order.capture().then(details => {
            alert("Transaction completed by " + details.payer.name.given_name);
            console.log("orderID is ");
            console.log(data.orderID);

            // Call your server to save the transaction
            return this.$store
              .dispatch(PRODUCT_PAYPAL, data.orderID)
              .then(() => {
                alert("success");
              })
              .catch(() => {
                alert("error");
              });
          });
        }
      })
      .render("#paypal-button-container");
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

As shown in the following screenshot, I was able to receive the orderID which means that the transaction was successful. However, this.$store is undefined. Hence, I can't send the order ID to my server

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an arrow function on your callback function, to have access to **this**.

```
onApprove: (data, actions) => ...

return actions.order.capture().then((details) => ...
```

Comment: Hi @Kris! Thanks for the reply, I've converted it to an arrow function and now I receive a different error message. This is the message:  this.$store.dispatch(...).then(...).err is not a function

Comment: @Issaki change err() to catch()

Comment: So instead of .err(() => { alert("error"); }); you have ".catch(() => { alert("error"); });"

Comment: Hi @Kris! Now I've received another error message: status (404) not found. I believe this has got to do with my API path so I will try to fix it. One last problem, sometimes which I click on the Paypal button, the external paypal window will immediately close by itself. I have to click on the button a few time, to prevent this strange behavior. I went to the console log and found this message Uncaught Error: Order Api response error: "name": "AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE",
    "message": "Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials. I will edit this post to screenshot the error

Comment: That's has to do with your API, yes. Since the call has been made. I'm not familiar with the PayPal API sorry, I cannot help you there. Consider marking my comment as the answer, if you got your question answered ;)

Comment: You got an error message though, so it seems like it either has to be because of wrong credentials or a missing authentication header.

Comment: According to the docs, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#1-set-up-your-development-environment I must include a Paypal script with the client id. I included this script tag at my index.html file. I don't know if this strange behaviour has got to do with the browser not receiving the client id **sometimes**?